# AndroidView displays full screen only in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, view, native

I have an issue with displaying `TextView` (or any kind of `view`) from Android Native code to Flutter.

What I want to achieve is this -> To have several Flutter Widgets, Android Native View (widget) in between. In Flutter App in one screen i need to display View from Native Android code, but the View that i receive from Android Native in to Flutter is displayed in full screen when added as only element in the `Scaffold`. When added in `ListView`, like the example blow, im receiving an error.

I need this Android Native `view` like i use `Text Widget` in Flutter, in between some other Widgets.

Followed this documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is used in the platform side to register the view.
    final String viewType = 'hybrid-view-type';
    // Pass parameters to the platform side.
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  PlatformViewLink(
                    viewType: viewType,
                    surfaceFactory: (BuildContext context, PlatformViewController controller) {
                      return AndroidViewSurface(
                        controller: controller,
                        gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
                        hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
                      );
                    },
                    onCreatePlatformView: (PlatformViewCreationParams params) {
                      return PlatformViewsService.initSurfaceAndroidView(
                        id: params.id,
                        viewType: viewType,
                        layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        creationParams: creationParams,
                        creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
                      )
                        ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
                        ..create();
    },),],),),],),),);
  }
```

Error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1706 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///C:/Repo/Test_Repo/flutter-hybrid-composition-demo/lib/main.dart:85:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1706:12)
#3      RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
#5      RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#6      RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSliverList#65918 relayoutBoundary=up14
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.reverse, scrollOffset: 965.8, remainingPaintExtent: 603.4, crossAxisExtent: 411.4, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent: 603.4, remainingCacheExtent: 1103.4, cacheOrigin: -250.0)
...  geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: Infinity, paintExtent: 603.4, maxPaintExtent: Infinity, hasVisualOverflow: true, cacheExtent: 853.4)
...    scrollExtent: Infinity
...    paintExtent: 603.4
...    maxPaintExtent: Infinity
...    hasVisualOverflow: true
...    cacheExtent: 853.4
...  currently live children: 0 to 0
RenderObject: RenderSliverList#65918 relayoutBoundary=up14
  needs compositing
  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.reverse, scrollOffset: 965.8, remainingPaintExtent: 603.4, crossAxisExtent: 411.4, crossAxisDirection: AxisDirection.right, viewportMainAxisExtent: 603.4, remainingCacheExtent: 1103.4, cacheOrigin: -250.0)
  geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: Infinity, paintExtent: 603.4, maxPaintExtent: Infinity, hasVisualOverflow: true, cacheExtent: 853.4)
    scrollExtent: Infinity
    paintExtent: 603.4
    maxPaintExtent: Infinity
    hasVisualOverflow: true
    cacheExtent: 853.4
  currently live children: 0 to 0
...  child with index 0: RenderIndexedSemantics#e0d09 relayoutBoundary=up15
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    semantic boundary
...    size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
...    index: 0
...    child: RenderRepaintBoundary#a66fc relayoutBoundary=up16
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      layer: OffsetLayer#23514
...        engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#cf5b5
...        offset: Offset(0.0, -964.7)
...      size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
...      metrics: 92.0% useful (2 bad vs 23 good)
...      diagnosis: this is an outstandingly useful repaint boundary and should definitely be kept
...      child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#77a02 relayoutBoundary=up17
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
...        child: PlatformViewRenderBox#728cc
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          layer: OffsetLayer#e89f7
...            engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#ee38b
...            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way.

Apparently I could use an wrapper `Widget` for `PlatformViewLink` like this:

```
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 300, 
        height: 250, 
        child: PlatformViewLink(
          ...
          ...
        ),
      ],
    ),
```